# Cannot change Scrapy settings

Tags: settings, scrapy

I want to download pages in Chinese, So i opened the command line and the python, and typed these code

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
settings.overrides['DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS'] = {'Accept':'text/heml,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language':'ch',}
```

but it didn't work. The 'Accept-Language' remained 'en'.
So i tried other settings, same thing happened. I just can't change the settings. 
Someone plz help me out, it drives me crazy! i spent 3 hours on it but got nothing.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

is

```
settings.overrides['DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS'] = {'Accept':'text/heml,application/xhtml+xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8','Accept-Language':'ch',}
```

supposed to say text/heml or html?